# Define primary key for several different objects in RavenDb

Tags: primary-key, ravendb

Lets say that I have one object like:

```
class First
{
    int key;
}

class Second
{
    KeyValuePair<int,int> keyName;
}
```

Is it possible in RavenDb to define primary key using different name than "Id"? Please note that I need to assign different key name for different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gwynnbleid1,
Yes, you can. You can define this using the Conventiosn.FindIdentityProperty, which you can customize on a per type basis.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for long response. Didn't notice your answer. Could you provide some simple example ?

Comment: I have found answer for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767273/raven-db-have-it-auto-generate-its-own-key

I don't know if it works because in ravendb management studio all documents seems to have autogenerated id rather than one specified.